# Trying to use CAST on a string to varchar after SET in UPDATE statement - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, casting, sql-update

I'm trying to cast a string to a varchar from user input on a web application. I want to change the value of one of the columns given a certain ID (Primary Key) and the column name is what I'm casting as the varchar.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION changeQuantities(productID varchar, warehouseID int, change int) 
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('UPDATE warehouses SET CAST(%I AS VARCHAR) = %s WHERE warehouseID = %s', productID, change, warehouseID)
    USING change, warehouseID;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The 'productID' is the column name, 'change' is the new value, and 'warehouseID' is the primary key for the table. 'warehouses' is the table. Here is the error I receive:

```
SELECT changeQuantities('bg412',1,100);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CAST"
LINE 1: UPDATE warehouses SET CAST(bg412 AS VARCHAR) = 100 WHERE war...
                              ^
QUERY:  UPDATE warehouses SET CAST(bg412 AS VARCHAR) = 100 WHERE warehouseID = 1
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function changequantities(character varying,integer,integer) line 3 at EXECUTE statement
```

I have another function just like it that uses a SELECT statement while casting the column name and it works just fine. Can I just not cast something after SET? I haven't found anything on this particular case, so I'm either going to be humiliated or I will help someone else out with similar issues. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `cast()` on the left side of the assignment - and you don't need it, as the data type of a column is known. If at all you would need to cast the *right* hand side of an assignment to the data type of the left hand side.

Assuming that `bg412` is a column name, you need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION changeQuantities(productID varchar, warehouseID int, change int) 
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('UPDATE warehouses SET %I = %s WHERE warehouseID = %s', productID, change, warehouseID)
    USING change, warehouseID;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

Unrelated, but: using the the ID of a product as a column name in a table seems like a horrible design. What do you do if you have a million products?